# Compare 1 column with 3 others and extract values from col1 that do not appear in other cols

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

Hey I have column A that has a list of text values, and have columns B,C,D which contain some of the same text values. I want to extract the values from Column A which do not appear in column B,C or D. I tried advanced filters and several formulas and nothing is working!

Answer (score 0):

You should really add any formulas that are close but here is one answer put it in E2 and copy all the way down as many rows as are in A.

```
=if(countif($B:$D,A2)>0,"Value is listed","Value is not listed")
```

Then just filter the table using this new column.

If you use an actual range ($B$2:$D$5) it will run faster then using the whole columns like I did above.